# Qt-designer: enlarging the window does not replace my items

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt-designer

To keep the question as simple as possible, I prepared a simple Qt designer form below

[image]

There is a Tab Widget on the left side and empty QWidget on the right side, the QWidget  as a GroupBox. The Groupbox has a radio and pusbuttons (you can see them on Object inspector window on the photo as well ). The tab widget has a line edit. The central widget has a gridlayout and horizontal qsplitter is used.

My issue is that when I enlarge the window, all items (lineedit, radiobutton, pushbutton) are on the fix position. Here is an example what I mean:

[image]

What I want is that when the window is enlarged the items should be placed on the bottom of the window, or if they are in the middle, then they should stay in the middle. ( I don't want size of the buttons/lineedits to be changed).

How can I do it?

Comment: Am I wrong or you don't have a layout setup for `tab`, `tab_2`, `widget` and `groupBox`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The items you want to move dynamically, with window resizing must be in a layout.
So, in the example you've posted, you need two layouts; one inside the tab widget, for the QLineEdit and at least one in the GroupBox for the radio button and push button.

If you want the radio and push button to be aligned horizontally, you can start by placing them in a horizontal layout, before placing that layout in another, which all reside in the group box.

When you start to add items to layouts, such as push buttons, you'll start to notice that they can get stretched, so you may need to set the size policies of the widgets.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the line edit to be centered horizontally, you will have to place two horizontal spacers on each side of the line edit and select the three together and set "Lay out Horizontally". This can found at the top toolbar in Qt Designer.

To always have it at the bottom of the tab widget, put a vertical spacer above the line edit in your tab widget. Then select the option "Lay out vertically" for the tab widget.

The same goes for your radio button and push button. Keep them in a horizontal layout, with horizontal spacers if required and put a vertical spacer into the group box and set the layout property for the group box as "Lay out Vertically".

Most important of all, I suggest you go through some basic tutorials before you continue. Here is a link to a good channel on youtube.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2D1942A4688E9D63

Comment: VoidRealms is the reason I got interested in Qt programming. :)

Answer (score 1):

**If you don't have a layout in your tabWidget or GroupBox:**

You must set a layout (for example QVBoxLayout)  inside your tab widget  and a group box.

It can be done using QtDesigner. It also can be done in code like this:

```
 QWidget *window = new QWidget;
 QPushButton *button1 = new QPushButton("One");
 QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("Two");
 QPushButton *button3 = new QPushButton("Three");
 QPushButton *button4 = new QPushButton("Four");
 QPushButton *button5 = new QPushButton("Five");

 QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
 layout->addWidget(button1);
 layout->addWidget(button2);
 layout->addWidget(button3);
 layout->addWidget(button4);
 layout->addWidget(button5);

 window->setLayout(layout);
```

**But if you do, and then you want your buttons to stay at the bottom:**

Then you have to try setRowStretch method http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html#setRowStretch or take a look at QSpacerItem.